# Manually Aligning Images in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, alignment

I did a little bit of search but I didn't find what I need. I have two images that I need to align. I just want to rotate them and/or change their scales manually. Is there any tool/program that helps me do this? Note that I cannot click on corresponding points because there might be none.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overlay both the images one on top of anther and keep rotating and scaling the top image till it coincides with the bottom image.

However you want to do this unsupervised, you can use Fourier Mellin Transform (FMT) which does this to a reasonable extent